# Phone number is not clickable in gmail in iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, email, html-email

When I click on the phone number it is opening the ios message compose screen, not open the dial pad.

My code is,

```
<a href='tel: 888-888-8888' style='color:#2275BB'> 888-888-8888</a>
```

Comment: Can you try without the dashes? i.e. tel: 888 888 8888

Comment: Also what meta tags do you have?

Comment: @Nathan, Yes have tried with tel:888 888 8888 but it also not working. 
And currently I'm not using any meta tags. It's just simple HTML page not have head tag.

Comment: Which email provider are you using? Some place tracking by default on any `href`'s. Tracking might cause issues as well

Comment: @Syfer I'm using gmail and outlook

Comment: If you are using Outlook to send emails, i suggest signing up to something like MailChimp. Outlook is not the best to send custom emails from.